# Expected Value of a continuous R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I quite understand the whole idea of this proof but I am just unsure about line $2$, how we went from $\int_x^{\infty}$ to $\int_0^{y}$

$\int_0^∞ 1-F(x) \ dx = \int_0^∞ \int_x^{\infty} f(y) \ dy \ dx $

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \int_0^∞ \int_0^{y} dx \ f(y) \ dy $ $\ \ \ \Leftarrow \ \text{here}$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \int_0^∞ y f(y) \ dy $

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = EX $

Answer (score 1):

When interchanging the order of integration, one must account for domain of integration.

Here, the integration covers the region for which $y\ge x$. Visually, this is a "triangular-shaped" region in the first quadrant, bounded by $x=0$ and $x=y$.

So, when we integrate with respect to $y$ first, the integral on $y$ goes from $x$ to $\infty$ and we write $\int_0^{\infty} \int_x^{\infty}f(y)dydx$.

Now, when we integrate with respect to $x$ first, the integral on $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$ and we write $ \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{y}f(y)dxdy$.  This is because $x\le y$ for all $y$.  So, the upper limit is bounded by $y$.

Answer (score 0):

It's switching the order of integration.

From $(x,y)\in[0; \infty)\times [x; \infty)$ to $(x,y) \in [0;y]\times[0;\infty)$

$$\;\int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=x}^\infty f(y) \;\operatorname d y \;\operatorname d x = \int_{y=0}^\infty \int_{x=0}^y f(y)\;\operatorname d x \;\operatorname d y$$

See also [Fubini's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) for further details.